# Nothing is showing

Tags: android

I'm working on an app where I have the option of "posting", when you press the post button you go to another activity where we have an `EditText` and a `Button`, once the `Button` is pressed the text should be taken and "posted" in the feed page in a `ListView`.

Now when I press the `Button` everything is working fine but nothing appears in the listview.

Here's the code:

Post:

```
package com.example.ali.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Post extends ActionBarActivity {
        EditText input;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        // android:id="@+id/input"
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

    }


    public void addToList(View v) {
        Editable text = input.getText();
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("result", text);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }

    }
```

The class where the message should be seen:

```
package com.example.ali.test1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {


    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        list= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


            if (requestCode == 1) {
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                    String result = data.getStringExtra("result");
                    adapter.add(result);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            }
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        int id2 = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (id2 == R.id.action_cart) {
            startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this , Post.class), 1);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

The xml files:

Post:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.test1.Post">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to list"
        android:onClick="addToList"
        android:layout_below="@id/input"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.test1.MainActivity">


    <ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that nothing is showing in the listview 
any help?

Answer (score 0):

Your not sending your intent.
`startActivity(intent);`

Then you are not receiving your intent on the other end properly.
You are using the `startActivityForResult();` strategy.

In your second activity call the `getIntent()` method to retrieve your intent and data.

Comment: so where do i add the getIntent() method?

Comment: In the receiving activity. `onCreate` seems the most logical as it is the first lifecycle method for an Activity.

Comment: Post your most recent code so I can see what you have done.

Comment: I only added  Intent intent = getIntent(); before my if statement in main

Comment: Post where you put it.